# Using FQL to retrieve facebook status's of all users who are using My Facebook Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like to retrieve status's of all users who are using my Facebook application.
I am not interested in retrieving the user's friends statuses only interested in retrieving the users who are using my Facebook application and have granted my application the "read_stream" permission.

I can successfully retrieve status's of the logged in user or one of the logged in user's friends by calling:

```
SELECT post_id, message, attachment, type FROM stream WHERE source_id = "SOME ID" AND type IN (46, 247)
```

But that is not my goal. I would like to get "All" users who are using my Facebook application and get their latest status feed without any particular user being logged in.

For example: I am not logged in facebook now neither or you. But when you click the link below you will get an RSS Feed of this particular user. This user is actually a business page so it is open to the public. Click This [Link](https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=152237754851522)

I would like to retrieve this information from users who allow my application "read stream" permissions.

I cannot retrieve this information on personal Facebook user pages. So I am under the impression I need to build a Facebook Application to do so.

Comment: Do you mean all users who are using it at the time you run the check or all users who have ever used it (or have used it in a particular period of time)?

Comment: I mean all users who have "EVER" used the application and my application still has the "read_stream" permission for that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve a list of the user IDs of your app's users, and if you already have the user IDs you already have the correct query format - you just use the access token from the users to make that call

The fact you can't retrieve a list is covered here: [Facebook. How to get list of all users of my app?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10071000/facebook-how-to-get-list-of-all-users-of-my-app)

If you need the status updates of all your users, you should probably be using the [Realtime Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) API to get a notification sent to your app when the user adds a new message, you can then use a cached [and still valid] access token for that user to retrieve the new messages

Comment: "you just use the access token from the users to make that call" - Are u saying capture each access token when the user grants access to my application along with the ID and save it to my external database. Then when i want to get the status of "all" users then reuse that old access token? I would think that the token would have expired by then. Thing is the user will not be logged in when I want to retrieve the status...  The 2nd statement regarding Realtime Updatesand cached  token may be the option...

Comment: Realtime Updates page says "Note that you can not subscribe to changes on all properties and connections of the User object. Connections to which you can subscribe include: feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies, television, likes, checkins, location, events." would my query i listed above fall into these categories???